# How I can use plugins in Adobe PhoneGap?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I'm trying to use plugins in my PhoneGap Build app but I put the  tag in my config.xml and not working.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install the plugin by using the command line interface.

**Steps to be followed**

install **Node.js**  use this link

```
  http://nodejs.org/
```

for sample if you using inappbrowser plugin then

navigate to the folder the project exist and

```
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git
```

if you have any doubts read this link,

```
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use the command line interface to add plugins.
for example:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file
```